# Find hyphonated words with Regex in list R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a string of semicolon-separated elements and I want to find if a pattern matchs with any of the elements in the string:

```
string <- "CPT1B;CPT1B;CPT1B;CHKB-CPT1B;CPT1B;CPT1B;CPT1B;CPT1B"
```

I want to know which regex use to match any of these elements, I mean, I want to get TRUE if any of the elements match with, for example, "CPT1B", to do so I use:

```
grepl(paste("[^;]","CPT1B,"[$;]",sep = ""),string)
TRUE
```

I used "[^;]" and "[$;]" because I want to get TRUE if any of the elements match.

My problem came when I try to match with "CHKB-CPT1B", because if I use the same expression:

```
grepl(paste("[^;]","CHKB-CPT1B","[$;]",sep = ""),string)
FALSE
```

I get FALSE, I think it's due to the hyphen in the word, and I'd like to know how to make grepl read the word with the hyphen as one word.

I don't want to use "CHKB\-CPT1B", because this pattern would came from an iterator that could be both hyphenated and non-hyphenated words. And I would also like not to split the original string by ";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use alternation groups:

```
grepl(paste0("(?:^|;)", "CPT1B", "(?:$|;)"),string)
[1] TRUE
```

The `(?:^|;)` non-capturing group matches start of string or `;` and `(?:$|;)` matches either the end of string or `;`.

You also may use lookarounds with `perl=TRUE` (i.e. a PCRE pattern):

```
grepl(paste0("(?<![^;])", "CPT1B", "(?![^;])"),string, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, the negative lookbehind `(?<![^;])` matches any location that is immediately preceded with `;` or start of string, and the negative lookahead `(?![^;])` requires the next char to be `;` or end of string location.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Both ways work for hyphenated words!! One thing only, could you explain me what are "alterantion groups"?

Comment: @LaureTomásDaza Alternation groups are [**capturing** `(...)` or **non-capturing** `(?:...)` **groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) containing [**alternation operator(s) `|`**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Thanks again!! It's been very helpful, I'll read these post about "Capturing/non-capturing groups"